# How to track the controller for the jsp in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on a Spring MVC project with annotations. I have a question suppose I open up a random jsp in the browser, is there any way to track the controller for that jsp?

Unlike the older versions of Spring where controller mapping for view was done in xml, from there we could possibly track the controller.

Answer (score 1):

look at the logs, or the source. Or write a java program that scans classpath for request mappings.

But multiple different controllers could serve one jsp - and it could be conditional.

Comment: +1 for `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. If you hadn't mentioned it, I would have been my suggestion ;)